# Declaring a parameter before a sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a simple table and want to to a query on it.

[image: s1]

The following code works well:

```
SELECT category1, COUNT(ID) AS ci, category2
FROM mytable
WHERE (variable1 is NULL) AND (yeardata <= 2008)
GROUP BY category1, category2
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;
```

[image: s2]

I now wanted to change this to:

```
DECLARE @yeardata smallint=2008
SELECT category1, COUNT(ID) AS ci, category2
FROM mytable
WHERE (variable1 is NULL) AND (yeardata <= @yeardata)
GROUP BY category1, category2
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;
```

However, when I try to run this I get an error message which says that delete, insert, select, procedure or update is expected?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that error message because this is not valid Access SQL ...

```sql
DECLARE @yeardata smallint=2008
```

You can declare a parameter in Access SQL like this ...

```sql
PARAMETERS [@yeardata] Short;
```

... but that does not allow you to assign a value to the parameter at the same time you declare it.

If you want to load the query results into a `Recordset` object, you could do it via a `DAO.QueryDef`, assign the parameter value, and then call its `OpenRecordset` method.

However, if you want to open the query directly in Datasheet View, you can supply the parameter value using [DoCmd.SetParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.setparameter) and then call `DoCmd.OpenQuery` like this example from the Immediate window ...

```vb
DoCmd.SetParameter "@yeardata", 2008
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"
```

Here is the SQL for my tested version of "Query1" ...

```sql
PARAMETERS [@yeardata] Short;
SELECT a.*
FROM all_tables AS a
WHERE (((a.notes) Is Null) AND ((Year([a].[date_created]))=[@yeardata]));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer, but what kind of sql is this then? How can I know that this is not valid Access SQL? When I google it I get pages like this: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/variables/ Where it gives examples like these?

Comment: Furthermore one question: Besides from the declare statement, is it valid Access SQL to use the @yeardata parameter later on? Would that work in Access SQL assumed that this parameter was properly filled in before?

Comment: You will be better served by Access rather that SQL Server documentation.  For parameter declaration, see [PARAMETERS declaration (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-declaration-microsoft-access-sql)

Comment: I mean, is it valid in Access SQL to have WHERE (variable1 is NULL) AND (yeardata <= @yeardata) ? Will this work, can I use @yeardata? Assumed that in a statement before this was filled properly. Is @parameter valid and does it work and is this the way in Access SQL to use a defined parameter (so that I do not have to enter e.g. 2008 manually or this is the result of a previous query)?

Comment: And what about the @parameter usage? (See my comment before)

Comment: I don't know, could you give a full working example? So I don't know how the whole query would correctly be specified.

Answer (score -1):

try something like:

```
DECLARE @yeardata smallint=2008;
BEGIN
SELECT 1
WHERE '2007' <= @yeardata;
END;
```

You need `BEGIN` and `END` after `DECLARE ....` and `<code>;</code>`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it, however, still the same error message.

Comment: @justin1012, unfortunately that's SQL Server (T-SQL) syntax, and it won't work with Access 2010.